# Can AppleScript get folder contents with file extension exclusion?

Tags: finder, applescript, folders

Looking for a way in AppleScript to get the contents of a directory with an exclusion to parse through. I know how to do this using `find` in a for loop with the command:

```
find . -not -name "*.bat"
```

but I'm curious to know if there is an **AppleScript only** approach to getting a folder's contents without the file extension `.bat`.

I've built a dummy directory on my desktop, added several files and tried:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to get every item of (entire contents of folder (choose folder)) whose kind ≠ ".bat"
    reveal theFiles
end tell
```

the `.bat` files are highlighted. Using `does not contain` compiles but errors out to:

Error:

> Can’t get every item of true.

Code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to get every item of (entire contents of folder (choose folder) does not contain ".bat")
    reveal theFiles
end tell
```

Trying another approach I get an error of:

Error:

> Finder got an error: Unknown object type.

Code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to get every item of (entire contents of folder (choose folder)) whose type ≠ {"public.bat"}
    reveal theFiles
end tell
```

If I try to modify the approach I can only get a solid result if I narrow down the name of a bat file using:

Code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to get (every file of folder (choose folder) whose name is not in {"foobar.bat"})
    reveal theFiles
end tell
```

In pure AppleScript is there a way to get contents of a directory with an exclusion for file type? I would possibly like to chain the exclusion for multiple file types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Finder

Here are a few different ways to filter by file extension, with a brief description of their benefits.  For the purposes of illustration, I've had *Finder* operations performed upon an open *Finder* window (my *Pictures* folder), which has many jpegs in it that serve as a good sample against which to test exclusion filters.

```
tell application "Finder" to select (every file in the ¬
    front Finder window whose name does not end with ".jpg")
```

This took 14 seconds on its second run, to provide a baseline for rough comparisons.

The one simple act of coercing the result to an `alias list` consistently sped up the performance time to 8 seconds (almost twice as fast):

```
tell application "Finder" to select ((every file in the ¬
    front Finder window whose name does not end with ".jpg") as alias list)
```

Surprisingly to me, filtering by `name extension` didn't seem to affect performance times compared to using the `name` property, possibly suggesting both are performing equivalent string comparisons under the hood:

```
tell application "Finder" to select ((every file in the ¬
    front Finder window whose name extension is not "jpg") as alias list)
```

Nonetheless, I would preferentially choose to filter by `name extension` as a matter of personal choice, because it's cleaner syntax.

One benefit of *Finder* is that we can condense multiple filters into one, inclusive expression that essentially forms a list of predicates:

```
tell application "Finder" to select ((every file in the ¬
    front Finder window whose name extension is not in ¬
    ["jpg", "png"]) as alias list)
```

and this was just as fast for two extensions than it was for one, and then again for four:

```
tell application "Finder" to select ((every file in the ¬
    front Finder window whose name extension is not in ¬
    ["jpg", "png", "mov", "mp4"]) as alias list)
```

Filtering by the `name` property can't be done with multiple extensions in this manner, so must be done with separate clauses for each extension you wish to exclude:

```
tell application "Finder" to select ((every file in the front Finder window whose ¬
    name does not end with "jpg" and ¬
    name does not end with "png" and ¬
    name does not end with "mp4" and ¬
    name does not end with "mov") as alias list)
```

---

#### System Events

*System Events* is much more equipped to handle file processing and filtering than *Finder*, which is somewhat counterintuitive.  It also prevents *Finder* being blocked during the operation.

You cannot use a list of predicates as you can with *Finder*, so we have to make do with the longer expressions:

```
tell application "System Events" to get path of every file in the ¬
    pictures folder whose visible = true and ¬
    name extension is not "jpg" and ¬
    name extension is not "png" and ¬
    name extension is not "mp4" and ¬
    name extension is not "mov"

tell application "Finder" to select the result
```

But the fact that this operation takes approximately **zero seconds** makes it worthwhile.  Note here that I asked *System Events* to return the `path` to these items, simply so I could then pass the result to *Finder* and have it select them as before (this is also how you can use `reveal` after a *System Events* call).

---

#### Objective-C

If you need to search huge folders or a nested list of folders, don't be tempted to use *Finder's* `entire contents` property, or it will make you cry.  Use AppleScriptObjC, which performs deep searches of folder trees with performance times that are faster than *System Events* and shell.  It comes at a cost of slightly more overhead compared to *System Events*/*Finder*, but probably comparable to that of calling a shell script.

First, it's best to define some handlers to take care of the file searching and filtering:

```
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

property this : a reference to current application
property NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles : a reference to 4
property NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsPackageDescendants : a reference to 2
property NSFileManager : a reference to NSFileManager of this
property NSMutableSet : a reference to NSMutableSet of this
property NSPredicate : a reference to NSPredicate of this
property NSSet : a reference to NSSet of this
property NSString : a reference to NSString of this
property NSURL : a reference to NSURL of this


on filesInDirectory:fp excludingExtensions:exts
    local fp, exts
    
    set all to contentsOfDirectory at fp
    set |*fs| to all's filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate's ¬
        predicateWithFormat:("pathExtension IN %@") ¬
            argumentArray:[exts])
    
    set fs to NSMutableSet's setWithArray:all
    fs's minusSet:(NSSet's setWithArray:|*fs|)
    fs's allObjects() as list
end filesInDirectory:excludingExtensions:

on contentsOfDirectory at fp
    local fp
    
    set FileManager to NSFileManager's defaultManager()
    
    set fs to FileManager's enumeratorAtURL:(NSURL's ¬
        fileURLWithPath:((NSString's stringWithString:fp)'s ¬
            stringByStandardizingPath())) ¬
        includingPropertiesForKeys:[] ¬
        options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles + ¬
        NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsPackageDescendants) ¬
        errorHandler:(missing value)
    
    fs's allObjects()
end contentsOfDirectory
```

Then, you can perform a call like this:

```
get my filesInDirectory:"~/Pictures" excludingExtensions:["jpg", "JPG", ""]
-- tell application "Finder" to reveal the result
```

Note that Objective-C will perform case-sensitive searches, so it's prudent to include file extensions to be excluded in both upper- and lowercase formats.  The empty string excludes folders (except when the folder name contains a period).

Objective-C performed a deep enumeration of my *Pictures* folder filtering out all jpegs to return a list of 643 files nested within that directory, and it did this in approximately **zero seconds**.  Neither *Finder* nor *System Events* can match this time (*Finder* won't respond after a while, and doing a deep search with *System Events* requires manually iterating through child folders, and deciding how to handle the nested list it returns, but it does it in an impressive 4 seconds).  The shell is just as fast for this number of files, but I am fairly confident from what I've read that Objective-C will out perform the shell's `find` command for large volumes of files.

You'll see I commented out the *Finder*'s `reveal` command: asking *Finder* to reveal 643 files in different folders was...um...unpleasant.  I don't recommend it.

---

#### Conclusion

① Utilise *System Events* to perform file searches and optionally retrieve file paths, which can be utilised for any operations you wish *Finder* to subsequently perform upon them.

② If you do, for some reason, need to use *Finder* to perform the file search, always coerce to *`alias list`* for performance benefits and a class of item that's universally much easier to handle later.

③ For large or nested folder structures, use Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to files in folder (choose folder) whose name does not end with ".bat"
    reveal theFiles
end tell
```

Comment: I will add a caveat that while this should work, and is what OP asked for, in my experience running do shell script will be *much* faster in a directory with lots of files. No idea why.

Comment: Use _System Events_ instead of _Finder_ to do the file searching, then _Finder_ to do the reveal.  Or, if you want to just use _Finder_, ask it to return an _alias list_, which is also faster.